# How to change the looking of GNOME?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

My current GNOME desktop looks like this:

[image]

where the dock is below the desktop, and it is visible only after I click Activities.

But I saw other people's GNOME desktop looks like this:

[image]

where the dock always shows up to the left.

Do you know how to change the looking of my desktop to the second one? Thanks.

========== Edit ===========

I have tried hard, but the desktop is always dock-style. Below is a screenshot where I specified the desktop to be ubuntu:GNOME at login, but it's still dock. I'm starting to suspect that Canonical forces Ubuntu 22.04 users to use dock desktop no matter what. If you are an employee of Canonical or an insider who can confirm my suspicion, I'll appreciate it because I don't have to waste time trying to change the desktop back to dash any more.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Appearance` and navigate down to ``` Dock > Position on screen`` after which select the down arrow and select ``` Left`.

You can also select right if that would be your preference.

[image]

Comment: My settings doesn't have Appearance option.

Comment: @zzzhhh that is quite odd. My instance (from where the image was produced) is GNOME version 42.l9 using X11 as the windowing system on Ubuntu 22.04. Are you sure you are using GNOME as your desktop environment. You can check which one by typing `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in the terminal. You should get `Ubuntu:GNOME`

Comment: I'm using GNOME 42.9 and X11 as windowing system on Ubuntu 22.04 too. `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns GNOME.

Comment: but not Ubuntu:GNOME ? Which distro are you using?

Comment: I can choose what desktop to use at login. Whatever I choose, GNOME or Ubuntu, the desktop is always dock, not dash. This is a screenshot where echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP returns ubuntu:GNOME: https://ibb.co/XympFnR. The distro is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS server installed from ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso downloaded from Canonical official website. Now I start to suspect Canonical forces Ubuntu 22.04 users to use dock desktop no matter what.

Comment: I managed to make the Appearance option show in Settings, and managed to make the Dock show in Appearance option, and then make settings in Dock exactly the same as yours. But nothing is changed; the desktop is still dock-style, not dash-style I desire. I put a screenshot under this configuration in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to extensions and find "dash-to-dock".
And then "Settings"
Make your choice for dock position.

If you don't have this extension for install please try this command:
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-dashtodock

Source: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

You can select themes and different customizations.
For this run "gnome-tweaks" command on terminal and then select appearence tab.

If you don't have already:
Please install gnome-tweaks with

`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks` command

Good luck

Comment: 1. my extensions doesn't have dash-to-dock. Of course I can install it, but 2. What I want is dock-to-dash, so the "dash-to-dock" extension doesn't help, for I'm in dock already. 3. I cannot find any function in Appearance tab of "gnome-tweaks" that can convert dock to dash. Nowhere else in gnome-tweaks has this function either.

Comment: source: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: "I cannot find any function in Appearance tab of "gnome-tweaks" that can convert dock to dash" - correct, that option odes not exist in Tweaks v42 beta GTK 3.24.33

Comment: @Ertan Mantas: To repeat: 2. What I want is dock-to-dash, so the "dash-to-dock" extension doesn't help, for I'm in dock already.

Comment: @graham: So you mean newer version of Tweaks has dock-to-dash option? What version?